# How do I declare and use a variable in crontab that will hold the name of the admin user account?

Tags: bash, cron, variable-substitution

I want the crontab for `root` to be  agnostic, i.e. I don't want to literally specify in it that the admin user is `jim`. That is why in my crontab for `root` I introduced the variable `au`.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

au=$(echo "$(head -n 1 /etc/doas.conf)"|sed 's/permit//;s/as//;s/root//;s/ //g')

5 */4 * * * /home/"${au}"/sync-w-oumaima.sh
* * * * * echo "$au">"/home/${au}/${au}.log"
```

Sadly, it does not work - `/home/jim/jim.log` does not get created by crontab.
How do I declare and use a variable in crontab that will hold the name of the admin user account?

Comment: Why not modify your script to derive the admin user? Then your crontab entry can be truly generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `crontab` format allows you to define environment variables but does not perform any substitution. In you example, the `au` variable is defined as the **string** `$(echo "$(head -n 1 /etc/doas.conf)"|sed 's/permit//;s/as//;s/root//;s/ //g')`.

The simplest solution is to explicitly define the user in your crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

au=jim

5 */4 * * * /home/"${au}"/sync-w-oumaima.sh
* * * * * echo "$au">"/home/${au}/${au}.log"
```

Another solution would be to write a simple script that sets the `au` variable and the run the “real” command and run that script from your crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash
export au=$(echo "$(head -n 1 /etc/doas.conf)"|sed 's/permit//;s/as//;s/root//;s/ //g')
/home/"${au}"/sync-w-oumaima.sh
```

A third solution would be to use the `eval` shell builtin to make your shell re-interpret the content of the `au` variable, with something like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

au=$(echo "$(head -n 1 /etc/doas.conf)"|sed 's/permit//;s/as//;s/root//;s/ //g')

5 */4 * * * eval /home/"${au}"/sync-w-oumaima.sh
* * * * * eval echo "$au" \> "/home/${au}/${au}.log"
```

But you’d have to be **extra** careful with the required escaping (I certainly was not careful).

Comment: I don't get the reason behind the **question**, but your answer is clever!

Answer (score 2):

First, improve the command for finding the `au` (admin user).

```
# Test with
sed -nr '1s/permit (.*) as root.*/\1/p' /etc/doas.conf
# When this looks fine
au=$(sed -nr '1s/permit (.*) as root.*/\1/p' /etc/doas.conf)
```

You can use it in your crontab

```
5 */4 * * * au=$(sed -nr '1s/permit (.*) as root.*/\1/p' /etc/doas.conf) && /home/"${au}"/sync-w-oumaima.sh
* * * * * au=$(sed -nr '1s/permit (.*) as root.*/\1/p' /etc/doas.conf) && echo "$au">"/home/${au}/${au}.log"
```

When you need to scroll to see your command, your command is too long. When you have more similar lines, it will become a mess. Why not create `/usr/local/bin/get_admin_user`:

```
# When this file is sourced (with a dot), the settings will remain available
export au=$(sed -nr '1s/permit (.*) as root.*/\1/p' /etc/doas.conf)
```

Next, source this file in your crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

get_au="/usr/local/bin/get_admin_user"

5 */4 * * * . ${get_au} && /home/"${au}"/sync-w-oumaima.sh
*  *  * * * . ${get_au} && echo "$au">"/home/${au}/${au}.log"
```